# Assign getActivity() explicitly

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment

How do I assign getActivity() by name explicitly? I have a viewpager with two fragments belonging to different activities.Let's say FragmentA and FragmentB. FragmentA extends BaseFragmentA and FragmentB extends BaseFragmentB. BaseFragmentA belongs to BaseActivityA and BaseFragmentB belongs to BaseActivityB.The ViewPagerAdapter containing the fragmentA and fragmentB belongs to MainActivity.So when i do getActivity() in any of these Fragments it gets me the MainActivity.But i actually want ActivityA or ActivityB.
Any workaround?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: I dont think it's possible for a fragment to "belong" to other activities than the one holding them at the moment.

Comment: that does not make sense. a fragment is in one activity at a time only.

Comment: and fragments don't "belong" to activities

Answer (score 0):

In both fragment override the onAttach method and you can try with the following code

```
 Activity fragmentAttachedActivity;

    @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if(context instanceof ActivityA){
               fragmentAttachedActivity= (ActivityA)context;
            } else if(context instanceof ActivityB){
               fragmentAttachedActivity= (ActivityB)context;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `void onAttach(Activity activity)` is deprecated, the new method is `void onAttach(Context context)`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce sorry I forgot...thanks for reminding me..I have edited it